# Python: How to share data between instances of different classes?

Tags: python, class, instance-variables

```
    Class BigClassA:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = 3
        def foo(self):
            self.b = self.foo1()
            self.c = self.foo2()
            self.d = self.foo3()
        def foo1(self):
            # do some work using other methods not listed here
        def foo2(self):
            # do some work using other methods not listed here
        def foo3(self):
            # do some work using other methods not listed here

    Class BigClassB:
        def __init__(self):
            self.b = # need value of b from BigClassA
            self.c = # need value of c from BigClassA
            self.d = # need value of d from BigClassA
        def foo(self):
            self.f = self.bar()
        def bar(self):
            # do some work using other methods not listed here and the value of self.b, self.c, and self.d


    Class BigClassC:
        def __init__(self):
            self.b = # need value of b from BigClassA
            self.f = # need value of f from BigClassB
        def foo(self):
            self.g = self.baz()
        def baz(self):
            # do some work using other methods not listed here and the value of self.b and self.g
```

Question:
Basically I have 3 classes with lots of methods and they are somewhat dependent as you can see from the code. How do I share the value of instance variables self.b, self.c, self.d from BigClassA to BigClassB?

nb: these 3 classes can not be inherited from each other, since it does not make sense.

What I have in mind, is just to combine all methods into a super big class. But I don't feel this is a right way to do it.

Comment: `class BigClassB(BigClassA):` and `class BigClassC(BigClassA, BigClassB)`. Use inheritance

Comment: You could try using a composition. That is when you instantiate an object of class A inside an instance of class B. That way you have the connection without saying one is a specialization of other. [Read here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html). Other than that, you can send an object of class A and assing the attribute you need to a new attribute in class B. Although that might break data consistency.

Comment: Do you want to share the data per instance of the class or globally?

Comment: Per instance not globally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct, in your case inheritance does not make sense. But, how about explicitly passing the objects during the instantiation. This would make a lot of sense.

Something like:

```
Class BigClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        ..
Class BigClassB:
    def __init__(self, objA):
        self.b = objA.b
        self.c = objA.c
        self.d = objA.d

Class BigClassC:
    def __init__(self, objA, objB):
        self.b = objA.b # need value of b from BigClassA
        self.f = objB.f # need value of f from BigClassB
```

While instantiating, do:

```
objA = BigClassA()
..
objB = BigClassB(objA)
..
objC = BigClassC(objA, objB)
```

Comment: Interesting, what kind of design or pattern is this? Is this a common thing or is there better way to resolve the problem?

Comment: @user74158 it may be too common to even have a name.

Comment: @user74158 This is not a design pattern or anything. Its just a standard means of achieving what you'd like to do. The idea is to establish explicit dependencies by passing dependant objects to the `__init__`.

Comment: @DavidZ re. that this might "be too common to even have a name", would this be an example of [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)? From the link: `class DerivedClassName(BaseClassName):` Not exactly as above, but close... I'm trying to leave terminology breadcrumbs for those, like me, new enough to not always know what to even search!

Comment: @Hendy No, this is something entirely different from inheritance. The syntax `name(othername)` means something very different here than it does in the part of the tutorial you're reading.

Comment: @DavidZ Gotcha, and thanks for setting me straight. Just object as argument to pull from some attributes?

Comment: @Hendy In the case of inheritance, there are no arguments involved. But you might want to ask a separate followup question so you can get a more comprehensive answer than I can provide in the comments.

Comment: The names are "interfacing", "separation of concerns" and "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: In actual terms, it's called `dependency injection`